# Why AddVector CUDA c++ is not working?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to add 2 arrays using CUDA , but it  didn't work .

I did all that it should be done:

1) I parallelized the VectorAdd function

2) I allocated memory to the GPu and moved the data to the GPU

3) And last thing i modified the function VectorAdd to  run on the GPU

This is the code :

```
#define SIZE 1024

__global__ void VectorAdd(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x ;

    if(i < n)
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main()
{
    int *a , *b , *c;
    int *d_a , *d_b , *d_c;

    a = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    b = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    c = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc( &d_a , SIZE * sizeof(int) );
    cudaMalloc( &d_b , SIZE * sizeof(int) );
    cudaMalloc( &d_c , SIZE * sizeof(int) );

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i ;
        b[i] = i ;
        c[i] = 0 ;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, SIZE *sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, SIZE *sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_c, c, SIZE *sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    VectorAdd<<< 1, SIZE >>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, SIZE);

    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        printf("C[%d] =  %d\n", i, c[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);

    return 0;
}
```

The output on the console is this :
`c[0] = 0 , c[1] = 0 , c[2] = 0 , c[3] = 0 , c[4] = 0 ....`

Why is that it should be :
`c[0] = 0 ; c[1] = 2 ; c[2] = 4 ....`

Comment: If you add a suitable `cudaGetLastError()` after each CUDA runtime call, what do you get?

Comment: I didn't , should i ?

Comment: Of course you should have cuda error checking!

Comment: What gpu do you use? As expected your code work fine on my system. On cards of compute capability 1.x the maximum number of threads per block are 512.

Comment: Works fine on my machine too. Check the compute capability just like @hubs says.

Comment: Looks fine, try to change size to 512

Comment: Yep guys you are right i forgot that my GPU card is old . So the problem for my was the SIZE that was 1024 so i just put it at 512 and it works . THANKS !!!

Comment: somebody please post an answer so we can get this off the unanswered list.  In the future, it's a good idea to do [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with cuda code.  I would suggest doing that *before* posting here to ask for help.

Comment: @hubs You should post an answer.

Comment: @AndreiTranca Of course you should check all possible errors (at least when hunting down the problem). Asking on SO should really only come after the "I've tried all I can think of" phase, and the eventual SO question should include all the information you've discovered in your earlier attempts at solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the problem depends on your used gpu. Your kernel is launched with 1024 threads per block. Since your gpu is of compute capability 1.x only 512 or 768 threads per block are supported. A detailed list can be found in the official [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities).
Because you didn't use proper cuda error checking, you weren't possible to get the error returned by the cuda runtime api. A good guide for cuda error checking is given by @talonmies in this  [SO answer/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).